# AngularJs custom directive with $http

Tags: angularjs

I'm sorry but I got some troubles with AngularJs.
I have to get an image from S3 bucket and I want to inject it inside directive but I'm lost to how make it. 
Here is what I made but, obviously it does not work and I'm pretty sure I'm in the wrong way.
No java code here because I know I properly get the image from S3 bucket.

```
.directive('logoApp', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: "<div class='logo' style='background-image: 
        url(data:image/png;base64,<image I want to inject>);'></div>",
        scope: {
            logoApp: "="
        }
    }
})
.service('StartService', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.logo = {
        getFileFromS3 : function () {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/**/{[path:[^\\.]*}'
            }).then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $rootScope.err({
                    title: 'Internal erro',
                    code: '500',
                    message: 'dialog_confirm_download_error'
                });
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Thank you

**EDITED**
I tried something like this and replace .service by .factory

```
.factory('StartService', function($http, $rootScope) {
    return {
        getFileFromS3: function () {
            return $http({
                      method: 'GET',
                      url: '/<something>'
                  }).then(function (data) {
                console.log("data" + JSON.stringify(data.data));
                $rootScope.err({
                    title: 'Erreur Interne',
                    code: '500',
                    message: 'dialog_confirm_download_error'
                });
            });
        }
    }
})
```

And I can see I get my image in "data.data" but unfortunately, this part doesn't display my logo and let '{}' empty

```
.directive('logoApp', ['StartService', function(startService){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: "<p>{{ logo }}</p>",
        controller: function($scope) {
        },
        link: function($scope) {
            console.log('start service ' + JSON.stringify(startService.getFileFromS3()));

            $scope.logo = startService.getFileFromS3();
        }
    }
```

Comment: any reason to use base64 instead of using url to that image?

Comment: Just a convention that I have to respect  : /

Comment: Just noticed you were using scope in your service?  I would remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be what you're looking for.  I have changed the restrict to 'E' so that it is an element level directive and also added `replace=true` which will replace your directive element with the template from the directive.

Using the directive in your html would be like so:

```
<logo-app></logo-app>
```

Hope this helps.

```
.directive('logoApp', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: "<div class='logo' style='background-image: 
        url(data:image/png;base64,{{vm.imageData}});'></div>",
        controller: ['StartService', function(StartService) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.imageData;
            StartService.getFileFromS3()
                .then(result => vm.imageData = result)
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        }],
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    }
})
```

Please check the   [plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/kfTLfHGHNDWNe7ZwpgHJ?p=preview) for a live example using the code above.

Comment: Well, I'm back, I'm sorry but it's still not working : / 
vm.imageData is undefined. 
I tried something else (I update my post)

Comment: @Shaï The code above should work fine.  Did you include the controllerAs property?  I've added a plunkr example to help you.

Comment: Oh great, I really don't know what I missed! But it's finally working, great thanks to you !